# What return type annotation to use if a function returns a module in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm writing a function to help with an optional dependency (similar to [pytest.importorskip](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest-importorskip)) and I'd like to type it, but unsure what type to use. Since I'm always returning a specific module or None, I think I can be more specific than "Any".

```py
def try_import_pyarrow():
    try:
        import pyarrow
    except ImportError:
        pyarrow = None
    return pyarrow
```

Comment: Just a heads up that "returns a module" is not useful information in most typing contexts. A module has arbitrary readable and writeable attributes, so ``ModuleType`` is barely more specific than ``Any``.

Comment: Yeah, I'd very much like to return that it's this specific module, e.g. `Optional["pyarrow"]`, but I get "module is not allowed in this context" errors.

Comment: I actually ended up going with `Any` because `pytype` doesn't seem to understand `ModuleType` at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of a module is accessible as [`types.ModuleType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType).

Comment: And if it can return `None` then one should type it as `Optional[ModuleType]`